# cannot activate python virtualenv but no error shows up

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I tried to install virtualenvwrapper on MacOS and everything got totally messed up. I had to even try to uninstall my whole python 3.6 and the wrapper and the virtualenv, because it stopped running as well. So now I finally managed to install virtualenv again and it creates environments. However, when I try to activate an environment with `source my_env/bin/activate` nothing happens. It looks as if it worked, but there's no `(my_env) $`. I am using ZSH and can't find a way to fix that. All questions on this here on SO have some errors, while I get none, so any help would be very appreciated. Also as to how to install Virtualenvwrapper without messing up everything else. Thanks!

EDIT: As per the suggestions: tried bash and didn't work either. It worked fine before on ZShell

Comment: You say "I am using ZSH and can't find a way to fix that". Can you just say `bash` to launch a new bash shell and source the `activate` script there? I actually usually prefer to use a subshell to activate a venv because then I don't need to worry about cleaning up the environment when I'm done, I can just `exit` the subshell.

Comment: doesn't work with bash either. It was all working fine with zshell before I tried to put virtualwrapper which everyone suggests.. and now tons of headaches.

Comment: Meh. `virtualenvwrapper` is just a tool. I don't use it and I don't feel like my workflow is missing anything. YMMV. Don't feel compelled to use a tool just because someone else uses it. If a tool helps, go for it, but if it causes more problems than it solves, don't worry about it.

Comment: indeed. But now I need to fix the regular virtualenv which I need for my work from tomorrow on.. and it's all messed up. So when I do my_env/bin/activate absolutely nothing happens, not even an error..

Comment: If your prompt doesn't contain the code to show the active virtualenv, it will merely look like it didn't work. What's your prompt code and can you check whether the env is actually active?

Comment: oh that's weird! @tripleee I ran `pip3 -V`, showed the version I ran from my regular python, sourced, then re-ran it and it shows `pip 19.0.3 from path/to/virtual_environments/env36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)`. You were right! Do you know how to make the env show in zsh? Please also post this as an answer so I can mark it. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't use zsh. Feel free to post and accept an answer of your own.